# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, Is it possible to see the code behind design view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I tried googling but had no luck finding the answer,

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Server management server and was wondering if you could use the design view to create the table and then look at the get the code/(query?) behind it?

[image]

e.g. Going from ^ To:

```
CREATE TABLE Member (
MemberNo VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
MemberTypeNo INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (MemberTypeNo) REFERENCES MemberTypeNo (MemberType),        
FirstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
LastName VARCHAR(15),
DateOfBirth DATE,
)
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**UPDATE: Solution as described by @Jeff Hornby**

[image]

Comment: This functionality (split code/design view) is in [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL Profiler to get the script as you created the table.  Or you can get the Create script once the table has been created but there is no way to actually display the SQL as you are trying to create the table as there is with views (which is what I assume you are looking for).

Answer (score 3):

You can have SSMS generate a script after you save an update by enabling the "Auto genereta change script" option. The downside of course is that the script is only generated the moment you save your changes.

- From the SSMS menus click on "Tools"
- Click on "Options..."
- Click on "Designers"
- Check the checkbox "Auto generate change scripts" as highlighted below

Answer (score 0):

You can right click somewhere in the designer area and choose "Generate Change Script" from the context menu. Or find the same option in the Table Designer menu. This will show the SQL statements needed to create the designed table (or modify it, if you're editing an existing table).